# Background image of button

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect, sencha-touch-2.1

I am trying to set image of a button but its not covering the whole button. I mean, background of button is still visible.

I am trying to do it at run time by providing different image for each button in a loop.

Here it is:

```
for(var i=0; i<tvStore.getCount(); i++)
   {
     var aButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button',
     { 
       margin:8,
      id:'button'+i,
      itemId:i,
      style: 'width: 110px;height:110px;background-image:url(someRandomWebURLToImage) !important',
```

But image is not covering all the button. or if image cannot be stretched then how can I make the button's background transparent?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iconCls` attribute to specify CSS like this:

```
{
    xtype           : 'button',
    iconCls         : 'cart',
    text            : 'Add to Cart',
    iconMask        : true,
    padding         : 10,
    margin          : 10,
    id              : 'addToBagBtn'
}
```

and CSS file should have:

```
.x-tab .x-button-icon.cart, .x-button .x-button-icon.x-icon-mask.cart {
    -webkit-mask-image: url('../../touch/resources/themes/images/default/pictos/shop1.png');
}
```